# undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass on .each statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to join two very large tables from a single database in Rails. To reduce the amount of database calls, I want to use the .includes method. However, when I use this on my query I get the following error:

**undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass** on **<% table_data.each do |d| %>**

I can't for the life of my understand where this is coming from and how to fix it.

My code:

```
class Planning < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :timeline, :foreign_key => "pcnrtoev"
  
end
```

```
class Timeline < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :Planning 

end
```

```
class OverviewController < ApplicationController
 
  def index
    @table_data = Planning.select(:pcnrtoev).includes(:timeline)
  end

end
```

```
index.html.erb

<%= render partial: 'datatable', locals: {table_data: @table_data} %>
```

```
_datatable.html.erb

***
<% table_data.each do |d| %>
    -do things-
<% end %>
****
```

**Edit**

If I change my initial query to

```
@table_data = Planning.select(:pcnrtoev).includes(:timeline).limit(50)
```

it seems to work. I still can't get to the data however, as it throws up this:

```
undefined method `telco_code_in' for #<Timeline::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f4880c13638>
```

at

```
  <% table_data.each do |d| %>
    <%=if d.timeline.any?
>>    telco_code_in = d.timeline.telco_code_in
    end %>
  <%end%>
```

**Edit**

It seems there is something wrong with the information I get from the database, rather than from the query itself. If I limit the output to 5000, everything is fine. If I limit the output to 10.000, I get the "No first method on .each"-error. Could this be because the Planning table can have one or more rows in the Timeline table?

**Planning schema**

```
create_table "planning", id: :integer, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "pcnrtoev", null: false
    t.string "postcode", null: false
    t.string "huisnr", null: false
    t.string "toev"
    t.index ["huisnr"], name: "huisnr"
    t.index ["id"], name: "id"
    t.index ["pcnrtoev"], name: "pcnrtoev"
    t.index ["pcnrtoev"], name: "pcnrtoev_unique", unique: true
    t.index ["postcode"], name: "postcode"
    t.index ["toev"], name: "toev"
  end
```

The Timeline table is a view instead of a table, so I don't have an actual schema for that. I scraped the code of everything that could cause the error, so this is my complete code for now.
Also, this is a pre-existing database, maybe that's useful information?

Comment: What is behind `-do things-`?

Comment: There is no `first` call in your code. Are you sure that you posted all the relevant code?

Comment: @Yakov It doesn't matter. Even if the code is empty, the error persists. @spickermann That's what bothers me. I never even used ```first```. But I don't know what else could interfere.

Comment: Is this a typo? `belongs_to :Planning `, also is should be `has_many :timelines`

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give you right code without schema but I will do my best to explaining your mistake. So when you write

```
Planning.select(:pcnrtoev)
```

you are basically saying to database. Hey give me all pcnrtoev columns from planing table. If you paste this code in console you will se something like this

```
   <Planning id: nil, pcnrtoev: INT>,
   <Planning id: nil, pcnrtoev: INT2>...
```

So your database returns you only pcnrtoev columns and all other columns are nill.(Including columns from timeline table).
I hope you see what went wrong.
If you still have problem with writing the query, give me schema of Planing and Timeline table.

Comment: That does fix the error I got from my edit to the query, but the first problem still persists. Why do I get the "no first method" on my each statement if I don't limit the output?

Comment: Can you please give me current code of planning and timeline schema and model, Overview Controller and view?